# How to use default 'None' value from the picklist in If condition?

Tags: apex, picklist

I have a field **Score** on an object and it's data type is picklist having values with the dafault value
**None**.The values are

```
    None
    Unknown
    1
    0
    -1
```

so in a class there is a condition like

```
 if((newScore.contains('Unknown') || (newScore.contains('None'))
{
isScoreChange = False;
}
```

But this not working for the None value.Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None is typically represented by an empty string (`''`) or a null value, depending on where the data comes from. Try:

```
if(String.isBlank(newScore) || newScore == 'Unknown') {
  isScoreChange = false;
}
```